# Adding Credentials to Service with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, service, credentials

Hi when automating the creation of services with PowerShell as part of a bigger script, i have come across a stumbling block with the credential side of the task:

Running:

```
 New-Service -Credential $dmhostcred -BinaryPathName "C:\$AppInstance\Data.Service.exe" -DisplayName "DataService $AppInstance Host Service" -StartupType Automatic -Description "Data $AppInstance Host_Service" -Name "Data Service $AppInstance Host Service"
```

Wont work. It WILL create the service but wont add in the password into the credentials field for the service. The creds are stored using the `Get-Credential` command in a variable earlier on in the script.

Obviously i dont want passwords stored as a string/in raw form in script.

To get around this, I found another method for achieving this, which worked, but involves a lot of beating around the bush:

```
$serviceName = "Data $AppInstance Host"
        $hostdescription = "Data Host"
        $exePath = "C:\Path to App Folder\Service.exe"
        $userName = "$host"
        $securePassword = convertto-securestring -String "$password" -AsPlainText -Force  
        $credentialsObject = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $securePassword
        New-Service -BinaryPathName $exePath -Name $serviceName -Description $hostdescription -Credential $credentialsObject -DisplayName $serviceName -StartupType Automatic
```

This does work but when creating multiple services, this is a nightmare, and i have to store the password as a string in another variable, i hope you can appreciate - I'm trying to cut down on having to re-enter the same details repeatedly, neither of these solutions work for setting up service accounts in an automated fashion.

Any help on how to achieve this in a much more straightforward manner would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = "myUser"
$server = "myServer"
$file = ".\password.txt"

# Store password in a file at the beginning of your script
Read-Host "Enter Password for $user on $server" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $file


# Retrieve password later on, whenever you need it
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, (Get-Content $file | ConvertTo-SecureString))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. What's the difference between the last line of your code and me just entering the username and password in via $credential = get-credential?

Comment: You can keep the encrypted password in a file and avoid re-entering it if that file exists. Just a little bit more convenient.

Comment: Thats excellent to bare in mind, although what i'm trying to achieve here is to run a script with the new-service cmdlet and it import the (service account) credentials from the $credential = get-credential variable (which is used throughout the script and so only entered once anyway). Can you think how to do this without the convoluted 2nd method i posted?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what is the issue. Just in case it is reusing a password let me suggest that a `pscredential` variable can be used many times. If you don't want to reuse credentials but just a password, then the `.Password` property can be reused as a `securestring` object. `get-credentials` doesn't validate credentials, so you can use it once with dummy username to ask someone to input secure information. Since this is a bit dirty then if you need the user to input a password then you need to read from the host and then convert it to a secure password type.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi, the first line of code doesnt work because New-Service wont accept or input the credentials from the credential variable (which is just the username and password input from $cred = get-credential. So, new service doesnt work out of the box, and that's my problem, to reiterate.

Comment: Without execution, just be aware that a windows service requires the `computername\username` pattern as username to work. Not sure what the New-`Service` does for the incoming `pscredential` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 New-Service -Credential $dmhostcred -BinaryPathName "C:\$AppInstance\Data.Service.exe" -DisplayName "DataService $AppInstance Host Service" -StartupType Automatic -Description "Data $AppInstance Host_Service" -Name "Data Service $AppInstance Host Service"
```

This does work now for some reason once i embedded the code into a function.

Thanks